# apply macro over multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

i am verry new here
i have a macro that coppy a row (45) and insert it a couple of times below that row(45)

i have assigned this macro to a button
now i'm looking for a way that if i click that button the macro apply's this command to all sheets

here is the macro i am using now

```
Sub finaleRijenToevoegenVoorschotFactuur()
    Dim xCount As Integer
LableNumber:
    xCount = Application.InputBox("Aantal rijen", "VERKOPEN DIE HANDEL", , , , , , 1)
    If xCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "the entered number of rows is error, please enter again", vbInformation, "testing"
        GoTo LableNumber
    End If
    Range("A42").Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(xCount, 0)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: You find all the Sheets with `Worksheets`, then loop them `For each sht in Worksheets` and you do `sht.Range("A42").EntireRow.Copy` and then `sht.Range(sht.Range("A42").Offset(1, 0), sht.Range("A42").Offset(xCount, 0)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown`, and `Next` of course you may have some Sheets you dont want to do this, so setup a Select Case or If statement to skip them.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy/Insert Multiple Rows in Multiple Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub finaleRijenToevoegenVoorschotFactuur()
    
    Const CopyRow As Long = 4
    
    Dim xCount As Variant
    Do
        xCount = Application.InputBox("Aantal rijen", "VERKOPEN DIE HANDEL", , , , , , 1)
        If TypeName(xCount) = "Boolean" Then
            MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If xCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "the entered number of rows is to small, please enter again", vbCritical, "testing"
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    
    Dim ash As Object: Set ash = ActiveSheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ash.Parent
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsCount As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        wsCount = wsCount + 1
        With ws.Rows(CopyRow)
            .Copy
            .Offset(1).Resize(xCount).Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End With
    Next ws
    
    Dim MsgString As String
    MsgString = "Worksheets processed: " & wsCount
    
    If wsCount > 0 Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ash.Select
        MsgString = MsgString & vbLf & "Rows inserted: " & xCount
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox MsgString, vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you verry much
Although i dont realy get where do i choose what row to coppy on each sheet and where to insert it back on each sheet is it where you placed 

.copy that i need to change to sht.Range("A42").EntireRow.Copy   ?

becouse when i do that i get an error  
Variable not defined  and it highlights sht

Comment: You need to change only the constant: `Const CopyRow As Long = 42`.

Comment: ah yes sorry i was looking at 2 comments at the same time 
it works but i think i need an delay in the second sheet.

so the plan is that i have in sheet 1 a list of data
at the end of that list there are some calculations now i want that button to add rows just in case i want to put more data in the list.
in sheet 1 it works perfectly becouse when i insert the rows he pushes down the rest of the data below line 42 

Sheet 2 is copy of sheet 1 only a bit diffrend layout so that means the list in sheet 2 is a copy from the list in sheet 1

Comment: i'll add a picture in the answer to make it more clear